# Run neural-style on Azure VM NC6 Showed 11GiB Total Memory

Tags: azure, styles, virtual-machine, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm new in deep learning. I just wanna test some ideas, so I played https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style on Azure VM NC6 successfully (NC6 is like a Instamatic to me ^_^). But I got some odd log.
Before the log, I should show the feature of NC6:

```
NC series：NVIDIA k80 GPU. Double GPU，4992 CUDA，24GB，double:2.91TFLOPS，flout:8.73TFLOPS.  
NC6：6 cores + 56GiB memory + 340GiB disk + 1X K80. $0.9/hour.

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 9909:00:00.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.11GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 9909:00:00.0)
```

I have two questions:

1. The log shows that Total memory is only 11GiB. But for NC6, memory is 56GiB, GPU is 24GiB. Neither of them is like 11GiB. I used top command, it showed that the available memory is about 55GiB. So how to use the NC6 VM more effectively? Is there some configuration? Or just add some python code (use config = tf.ConfigProto() to change the allocation way of GPU memory?) in neural-style?
2. The log showed six warnings about SSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2. AVX, AVX2 and FMA which are all about CPU computation. Should I ignore the warnings in GPU computation mode?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Fix code indent.

Comment: Question 1: https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style/issues/91#issuecomment-313290278